# javascript break label showing syntax error

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, break

I have the code below :

```
 LableName_1:    
  if(ttipPos == 'left') {   
     //do sumthing  
     break L;  
   }    
  LableName_2:            
  if(ttipPos == 'right') {  
     //do sumthing  
     break LableName_1;  
   }
```

where I used `break` with label name

This is showing syntax error, but if I replace `break LableName_1` with `break LableName_2` within second `if` statement, the syntax error doesn't occur .... Is there any problem related to scope of using `break` with label.

Comment: `break` is a keyword in JavaScript. what are you trying to do?

Comment: You shouldn't be using `break` with if-statements

Comment: Indeed, what is your goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second break fails because it isn't inside of label #1. It can't break something it's not in.

```js
LabelName_2: {
  LabelName_1: {
    while (1) {
      console.log('label 1');
      break LabelName_1;
    }
  }
  console.log('label 2')
  break LabelName_2;
}
console.log('out of labels');
```

Comment: Ok...but cant we go to LableName_1 directly from he second if statement...is there any way like goto(I know that javascript has no goto statement)..but is there any other way like goto etc so that we can directly jump to LableName_1 ?

Comment: By using a function call. They are basically gotos, in a sense. I'd help you more if I knew what you were trying to do.